# Отображение направления маршрута

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Можно ли указывать направление движения маршрута multiRouter? Если готового решения нет, подскажите, пожалуйста, возможности его реализации.

Comment: Хоть бы ссылку или картинку добавили, нельзя хрустальный шар по таким мелочам расчехлять.

Comment: Поможет собственную реализация макета стрелки https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/arrow и последующая отрисовка совместно с точками маршрута.